# Using socketio in redux actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, redux

I'm trying to build an application using React, Redux and socket.io !
My question is : how do you initialize event listeners (which are actions in Redux) like this one :

```
export const addNotif = () => (dispatch) => {
  socket.on('notification', (message) => {
    dispatch(notification(message))
  })
}
```

in React without having access to the componentWillMount since I'm using functional programing on components.

My current problem is that if I pass the method

> addNotif

to my component, every time a new notification comes in, the store is updated, and so the component is re-rendered and therefore it adds another socket.on event and this keeps on going.

Any ideas on how to fix that in a clean way ?
Thanks !

Comment: Here's an example of a small program that uses sockets in the redux handler https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/using-socket-io-in-react-redux-app-to-handle-real-time-data-c0e734297795, maybe it will help a bit

Comment: @SterlingArcher sadly it doesn't ! The only place where he uses socket.on in Redux, he doesn't call the action afterwards (it is commented in the code :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, you don't want to attach an event listener inside a stateless function.
You wanna invert this: `notification comes in > dispatch event`. This can live outside the lifecycle of react since you can dispatch arbitrary redux actions from anywhere.

If the action is not consumed because there are no clients that's fine. You can fine tune this by absorbing/demuxing events in a redux middleware and/or have components dispatch subscriptions.

**index.js**

```
// start() should be called ONCE wherever you have access to the store 
const notifications = require('./notifications');
notifications.start(store.dispatch);
```

---

**notifications.js**

```
export default {
  start(dispatch) {
    socker.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Subscribed to notifications');
    });
    socket.on('notification', (payload) => {
      dispatch(({ type: "NOTIF", payload }));
    });
    socket.on('error', (message) => {
      console.log('TODO: handle error');
    })
  },
};
```

It might be a good idea to abstract away the socketio interface, hence the two files although it's not necessary.

Comment: Mmmh I kinda like this approach, but I got something to work with initializing the function addNotif in the container and not giving it as props to the child, is this a bad practice ?

Comment: I think it's somewhat confusing to attach an event listener inside a redux action. It's not clear that it will not be dispatched again which would cause leaked event listeners.

Answer (score 3):

Try to define and export the function like this:

```
export const addNotif = (dispatch) => {
  socket.on('notification', (message) => {
    dispatch(notification(message))
  })
}
```